# Sandbox Recurring Payments with SCM are just regular payments?

Tags: paypal, subscriptions

So I'm trying to test recurring payments/subscriptions with EllisLab's Simple Commerce Module.

I've got sandbox buyer/merchant accounts setup. Former has generated verified bank, latter has enhanced recurring payments enabled, encrypted payments enabled, IPN enabled (I receive DEBUG emails and logged in member purchases appear).

Everything seems to be in order... but when I make a recurring payment via the `{subscribe_now_url}` link it only seems to be a regular payment.

These are individual test purchases from the buyer's account screen:

[image]

And here is a sample of daily recurring payments from another project that used the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/#id086513007E9) (note the *"**Recurring** Payment To"* as opposed to *"Payment To"*):

[image]

In the Simple Commerce Module Edit Purchases tab it shows the purchases as "Recurring". However, there is no sign of it being a recurring payment anywhere else, neither on the sandbox Buyer's end, nor on the sandbox Merchant's end. Is it still somehow a recurring payment? Does it start recurring payments the next day (testing as daily subscription)? Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Tested with encrypted payments turned off and it works. My head hurts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really simple bug in Simple Commerce Module.

Open up `mod.simple_commerce.php` and look for where it's supposed to encrypt the subscribe data, it's around line 200. If you look carefully you'll find it's encrypting data for a regular payment not the `$subscribe` variable immediately above. Yeah, just change it to use `$subscribe` for encryption.

Mission accomplished.

**edit:** looked for a bug report on this and couldn't find one, so filed one here (contains actual code): https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19896